# Alternative to Microsoft Agent / Fix for color issue?

Tags: vb.net, colors, microsoft-agent

I've got an app that does Text-To-Speech; but I wanted to show an animated face/character to go with it.  I found a tutorial on Microsoft Agent and I implemented it in my vb.net app.

The problem is with the transparency color.

Unless I run application in compatibility mode/256 colors, the characters will appear with a purplish-pink background image instead of a transparent back-color.  But running the app in 256 colors the rest of the app looks awfully out of place.

First - is there something that works similar to MS Agent I can use that would be more appropriate?

Second - if I'm still MS Agent - can I get the transparent color to work correctly without limiting myself to 256 colors?

Comment: How old was this tutorial on Microsoft Agent? I don't think that's a modern technology.

Comment: @John - You're right; it's old and from what I've read was no longer supported as of Windows 7.

The downside is that it does pretty much exactly what I wanted.  I'm muting the sound from MS Agent and doing the speech-to-text with a more modern library; I just wanted an easy way to get an animated face/mouth that kinda-sorta matched up with the speech.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an open/free alternative implementing same interface and supported 32/64 Windows 7 http://www.cinnamonsoftware.com/double_agent.htm